# Access Tab Control fore color changes when hiding pages

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access, I have a TabControl called tbIMD.

The Back color is #604C78,
The Fore color is #F3F0F6,
The Hover color is #F3F0F6,
The Hover Fore color is #604C78,
The Pressed color is #FDFDFD,
The Pressed Fore color is #604C78.

The moment I hide a page via VBA, anytime I click on a page, all of the other pages' fore colors changes to the Pressed Fore color, which means that the back color and fore colors are now the same, so you can't read the text.

The code is as follows:

```
If DLookup("Purchased", "ItemCategoryT", "ItemCatID = " & Me.ItemCategory) = True Then
    Me.pgPurchaseInfo.Visible = True
    
    Else
        Me.pgPurchaseInfo.Visible = False
End If
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have been searching and searching and even ChatGPT can't help with an answer...

What I did was create a similar tab control and then just hide the tab control based on the criteria, instead of hiding the pages.

This seems to have solved my problem.

I would however love to know why it does this and whether there is actually a solution...